# How to Perform A JOIN operation in CodeIgniter and fetch results?

Tags: php, codeigniter

for a CI System,i have a reseller table and Users tables. each user is mapped to its reseller by a field called **KEY**  which is unique string. It's in both users table and reseller's table each user(record) has a reseller key mapped to it. I hope you understood the concept. Now i want to create a view for admin. Currently i show the list of `reseller` and list of users,Now how to create a view in which when i click on `reseller` i can see only his reseller?

here i fetch all the reseller in `index` function how to filter based on key

```
    public function index ()
        {
            $usertype=$this->session->userdata('usertype');
            if($usertype ==="admin")
                {
                    // Fetch all users
                    $this->data['users'] = $this->reseller_m->get();
                    // Load view
                    $this->data['subview'] = 'admin/reseller/index';
                    $this->load->view('admin/_layout_main', $this->data);
                }
            else
                {
                    $this->load->view('permission');
                }   
        }
```

Comment: have you googled yet ? checkout ci [active records for join table](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)

Comment: yeah i did but dont know how to use in my scenario @Gowri

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [CI active records](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html) like this

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('reseller');
$this->db->join('users', 'reseller.KEY = users.KEY');
$this->db->WHERE('reseller.key',$reseller_id);
$result = $this->db->get();
```

Just change the result input to the view. On first page you passing result of all the user result, so if the user clicks on the specific reseller then basically you have to pass the reseller id to the controller, right? using that id just switch the query result to the view by if else condition.

```
    public function index ()
        {
            $usertype=$this->session->userdata('usertype');
            $reseller_id=$this->input->get('reseller_id');
            if($usertype ==="admin")
                {

              if($reseller_id){

                    // Fetch only resellers users

                  $this->db->select('*');
                  $this->db->from('reseller');
                  $this->db->join('users', 'reseller.KEY = users.KEY');
                  $this->db->WHERE('reseller.key',$reseller_id);
                  $this->data['users'] = = $this->db->get();

                  }else{
                    // Fetch all users
                    $this->data['users'] = $this->reseller_m->get();

                 }
                    // Load view
                    $this->data['subview'] = 'admin/reseller/index';
                    $this->load->view('admin/_layout_main', $this->data);
                }
            else
                {
                    $this->load->view('permission');
                }   
        }
```

Comment: i mean if click on reseller how to load only that users on view

Comment: just change the result input to the view. On first page you passing result of all the user result, so if the user clicks on the specific reseller then basically you have to pass the reseller id to the controller, right? using that id just switch the query result to the view by if else condition.

Comment: So i should that pass it in achor tag?

Comment: i mean should i create a seprate page?

Comment: Yes of course! It's deepens on you. If you want to show in different format then you need to create another  view else if you want to switch only the results no need

Comment: aah got too confused  :( dont know what to do

Comment: if i use a achor tag what could be the possible link to show this result

Comment: haha rajan no need to panic! View is only for presentation. If you want differentiate the presentation b/w all users and specific reseller user you need to create he different view. just move the load view inside if statement else why need another view

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88790/discussion-between-rajan-and-gowri).

Comment: dont i need to check the $key in if statement?

Comment: how to diffrentiate between users id and reseller's id

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
// Fetch all users
$this->data['users'] = $this->get('users');
foreach($this->data['users'] as $ind=>$row){
  // then connect resellers to each user
  $this->data['users'][$ind]['resellers'] = $this->reseller_m->->where('key', $row['id'])->get();
}
```

First you get all users to array and connect to each user his resellers. I expect you have defined "reseller_m" as model and with method where() which i **edited** now you specify only recellers of user.

Or this row will do the same I think: (without defined model)

```
$this->data['users'][$ind]['resellers'] = $this->where('key', $row['id'])->get('resellers');
```

Comment: I appreciate your help but  could please explain you code